# Webcenter Portal and Content Management

Tags: oracle, portal, content-management, content-management-system, webcenter

Is it possible to use WebCenter Portal to store and version documents (pdf, doc, xls etc) without buying WebCenter Content separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebCenter portal comes with limited Webacentr content license, so you can have the basics of Universal content management in your portal

Comment: I have also verified this answer from oracle sales department.